# NHibernate where not exists with QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have an entity GameSystemDAO and an entity ContestPlanningGSItemDAO with a property GameSystem which is a many-to-one of type GameSystemDAO. What is a QueryOver expression which corresponds to the following SQL?

```
select *
from gamesystemdao g
where not exists (
  select *
  from contestplanninggsitemdao cpgsi
  where cpgsi.gamesystem = g.id)
```

I tried the following (and many other variations):

```
GameSystemDAO gameSystemAlias = null;
ContestPlanningGSItemDAO contestPlanningGSItemAlias = null;
List<GameSystemDAO> newGameSystems = session.QueryOver<GameSystemDAO>(() => gameSystemAlias)
                    .WithSubquery
                    .WhereNotExists(
                        QueryOver.Of<ContestPlanningGSItemDAO>(() => contestPlanningGSItemAlias)
                        .Where(() => contestPlanningGSItemAlias.GameSystem.Id == gameSystemAlias.Id)
                        .Select(c => c.GameSystem))
                    .List();
```

but always get a *KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary*. It seems like NHibernate is looking for a property named *gameSystemAlias* on the ContestPlanningGSItemDAO instance.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a complete stacktrace most often helps a lot so plz always post it from the beginning

Comment: @Firo Exception is being thrown at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.ToType(string propertyName), line 37 (using NHibernate 3.2.0)

Comment: Thanks for posting, this got me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that updating to NHibernate 3.3.1 gets this to work; I was using NH 3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

exchange

```
QueryOver.Of<ContestPlanningGSItemDAO>(() => contestPlanningGSItemAlias)
    .Where(() => contestPlanningGSItemAlias.GameSystem.Id == gameSystemAlias.Id)
    .Select(c => c.GameSystem))
```

with

```
QueryOver.Of<ContestPlanningGSItemDAO>()
    .Where(x => x.GameSystem == gameSystemAlias))
```

Comment: In this way NHibernate does not throw exception anymore but is generating wrong sql, in particular in the sub-query it is generating a where condition like this: `SELECT this_0_.GameSystem as y0_ FROM ContestPlanningGSItemDAO this_0_ WHERE this_0_.GameSystem is null` instead of joining it with the outer query